# Convert User's Avatar/Gravatar to a jpg or png on the Fly

Tags: images, avatar, gravatar

Is there a way to convert a user's gravatar/avatar to jpg on the fly?
I have the following in my function:

```
get_avatar( $uid, 180 );
```

which returns the user's avatar image if I call it with straight PHP (i.e.: `<?php echo get_avatar( $uid, 180 ); ?>` but I want to convert the resulting file to a jpeg/png image so I can insert it into an FPDF function

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`get_avatar`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) function returns the Gravatar wrapped in `<img>` tags. In your case you'll want to use [`get_avatar_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url) to get just the URL of the image you need.

Combine that with WordPress' `wp_remote_get` and you can grab the image data into a variable or save it as an image.

```
$user            = wp_get_current_user();
$gravatar_url    = get_avatar_url( $user->ID, ['size' => '50'] );
$gravatar_source = wp_remote_get( $gravatar_url );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $gravatar_source ) && 200 == $gravatar_source['response']['code'] ) {
    $filename      = sanitize_file_name( $user->ID . '.jpg' );
    $gravatar_file = fopen( 'tmp /' . $filename, 'w' );
    fwrite( $gravatar_file, $gravatar_source['body'] );
    fclose( $gravatar_file );
}
```

This example is copied from  [this script](https://gist.github.com/iandunn/5ccc8f8a01ccb1a981c3#file-camptix-gravatar-badges-php-L60) which is otherwise largely unrelated.

Edit: If you just want to grab the URL into a PHP variable you can do this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$userdata     = get_userdata( $current_user->ID );

$gravatar_url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5( strtolower( trim( $userdata->user_email ) ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. get_avatar_url() would be fine - the resulting file doesn't actually need to be converted to a jpeg. This currently returns a png file (https://toogeemartialarts.com/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/<uid here>/profile_photo-190x190.png?1589039606). What is the number at the end of the file name? If I can just remove that, then everything is fine as is. Alternatively, I can use the script you provided but I am not sure how to find the path to the file?

Comment: "This currently returns a png file". What PHP code?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter before I was finished. This gives me the path to the PNG file: `<?php echo get_avatar_url( $uid ); ?>`

Comment: The part at the end is the [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). It's added there for cache busting. You can remove it, maybe with a bit of regex?

Comment: Or generate the URL yourself with just PHP https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

Comment: Thanks @brooke. I got it working with the following: `$userPhoto = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', get_avatar_url( $uid, 180 ) );` which returns the url without the timestamp query at the end. Now I just need to get FPDF to recognise the filename (seems to think it is empty…)

Comment: Great, if my answer helped will you make sure it's marked as correct to help others?

Comment: Done. Thanks again :)